# Why MVC complex property is null?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, properties

**A) My Model (Code First)**

```
public class CategoriaDeProduto
{

 public int Id { get; set; }
 public string Descrição { get; set; }
 public string Observação { get; set; }

 //This property contains high level product types of this product type 
 public ICollection<CategoriaDeProduto> CategoriasDeProdutoMae { get; set; } 

 //This VIRTUAL property contains low level product types of this product type 
 public virtual ICollection<CategoriaDeProduto> CategoriasDeProdutoFilho { get; set;} 

}
```

**B) My "Seed File"**

```
   context.CategoriaDeProduto.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Id,
     new CategoriaDeProduto
     {
         Id = 1,
         Descrição = "TV",
         Observação = "TV"
     },
     new CategoriaDeProduto
     {
         Id = 2,
         Descrição = "Impressora",
         Observação = "Impressora"
     },
     new CategoriaDeProduto
     {
         Id = 3,
         Descrição = "Multifuncional",
         Observação = "Multifuncional",
     },
     new CategoriaDeProduto
     {
         Id = 4,
         Descrição = "Smartphone",
         Observação = "Smartphone"
     }

  );

    context.SaveChanges();



     context.CategoriaDeProduto.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Id,
     new CategoriaDeProduto
     {
         Id = 9,
         Descrição = "TV LCD",
         Observação = "TV de tecnologia LCD",
         CategoriasDeProdutoMae = new Collection<CategoriaDeProduto> { context.CategoriaDeProduto.Find(1), context.CategoriaDeProduto.Find(2), context.CategoriaDeProduto.Find(3), context.CategoriaDeProduto.Find(4) }

     }


     );


   context.SaveChanges();
```

**C) My "View"**

```
@model IEnumerable<Serelepe2014.Models.CategoriaDeProduto>
@(Html.GeraListagemEstiloClasse<Serelepe2014.Models.CategoriaDeProduto>(Model,@Resources_us.CategoriaDeProduto,@Resources_us.CategoriaDeProduto));
```

**D) My Html Helper Extension "GeraListagemEstiloClasse"**

```
  public static MvcHtmlString GeraListagemEstiloClasse<T>(this HtmlHelper oHtmlHelper, IEnumerable<T> data, string tituloNoBrowser, string tituloNaTela)
        {

          ...

        }
```

**E) MY PROBLEM**

GeraListagemEstiloClasse is receiving data parameter (IEnumerable type) with problem on a element.

PROBLEM: My "CategoriaDeProdutoMae" complex property of 8o element comes with null value , but you can see on details of this post that the correct was 4 objects and not null...

If, on "Quick Watch Window", I click on first element "CategoriaDeProdutoFilho" property 
then My "CategoriaDeProdutoMae" complex property of 8o element comes without null, comes with count == 1

If I repeat the proccess of open "CategoriaDeProdutoFilho" property of 2o, 3o and 4o elements, the complex property type "CategoriaDeProdutoMae" of 8o element comes with count ==4 ....

> Why complex property type "CategoriaDeProdutoMae" of 8o element not
>   comes with count ==4 without I click on another properties of another
>   elements ? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Impossible to answer without the contents of the view, which you have posted as an empty HTML helper.

Comment: No, the problem dont occurs on the view body..... the parameter already have problem on property value .... the contents of the view is not necessary ....

Comment: On StackOverflow I cannot post pictures ..... with pictures you will see that data parameter already have the problem ...

Comment: Breakpoint on html helper call already show the problem ...]